# JQuery: purpose of $(this).next versus omitting it?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".content").hide();
        $(".menu2sel").click(function() {
            $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(200);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Notice **$(this).next**

And this same script with the .next event omitted:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".content").hide();
        $(".menu2sel").click(function() {
            $(".content").slideToggle(200);
            });
        });
</script>
```

What is the function/purpose of the **$(this).next** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It selects the next element in the DOM, omitting it would select the current element instead.

The difference is that the first function **only** selects the next element if it has a matching class, while the second function selects **all** elements on the page with the class `content`.